# Setting dynamic data to min and max attributes of @Range annotation - hibernate validators

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

Iam using Hibernate Validator for validation of data. I have used @Range attribute for validating a particular field.

```
@Range(min=0,max=100)
private String amount;
```

This is fine but can i dynamically change the values of min and max instead of hard coding. I mean can i do something like:

```
@Range(min=${},max=${})
private String amount;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Annotations in Java uses constants as parameters. You Cannot change them dynamically.

Compile constants can only be primitives and Strings.Check this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).

IF you want to make it configurable you can declare them as static final.

For Example:

```
private static final int MIN_RANGE = 1;

private static final int MAX_RANGE = 100;
```

and then assign in annotation.

```
@Range(min=MIN_RANGE,max=MAX_RANGE)
private String amount;
```

**The value for annotation attribute must be a constant expression.**

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring in your project, you can do something like this:

properties file:

```
min_range = 0
max_range = 100
```

spring.xml:

```
<context:component-scan
    base-package="com.test.config" />
<context:annotation-config />

<bean id="appConfigProperties"    class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:appconfig.properties" />
</bean>
```

java:

```
@Range(min=${min_range},max=${max_range})
private String amount;
```

It's not dymanic change, but i think you trying to find something like this